# Galois group over $F=\mathbb{F}_3(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_3(t)$. Let $f(x)=x^6+x^4+x^2-t\in F[x]$. You may assume that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. Let $E$ be splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$.

> a) Show that $f(x)=f(-x)$ and $f(x+1)=f(x)$
>
> b) Determine $Gal(E/F)$

Hint: why is part a) there?

I proved $a)$ but i dont know how to answer $b)$, please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Part (a) has the consequence that, if $r$ is a root of $f$ in an extension field, also $r+1$, $r+2$, $-r$, $-r+1$ and $-r+2$ are roots.

Note also that these are pairwise distinct:

- $r\ne r+1$, $r\ne r+2$, $r\ne -r$, $r\ne -r+1$, $r\ne -r+2$;
- $r+1\ne r+2$, $r+1\ne -r$, $r+1\ne -r+1$, $r+1\ne -r+2$;
- $r+2\ne -r$, $r+2\ne -r+1$, $r+2\ne -r+2$;
- $-r\ne -r+1$, $-r\ne -r+2$;
- $-r+1\ne -r+2$.

How many roots can the polynomial have?

Comment: the number of roots is less then 6?

Comment: @siiwar It is *at most* $6$ in any field extension. Since there are six in $F(r)$, this is the splitting field for $f(x)$.

Comment: and what is $Gal(E/F)$ so?

Comment: @siiwar For instance there surely is an automorphism mapping $r$ into $-r$. Is there one mapping $r$ into $r+1$?

Comment: i don't see that clearly

Comment: @siiwar An automorphism mapping $r$ into $r+1$ must map roots into roots; for instance $-r$ would be mapped into $-r-1$, which equals $-r+2$. Can you go on?